# How to specify separate toolbar group for widget buttons?

Tags: widget, ckeditor, toolbar

By default CKEditor places widget buttons in the toolbar 'insert' group. I'd like to specify a custom group on the toolbar only for my widget buttons. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In such case you need to register the button yourself so to have a full control over it.

1. In the [widget definition](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition) do not specify the `button` property.
2. Add button using the [`ui.addButton()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui-method-addButton) method. This button should use the widget command which is created automatically based on the widget name.

So it could look like this:

```
editor.widget.add( 'myWidget', {
    // For the widget command to work you have to
    // specify at least template or insert() callback. 
    template: 'foo',

    ...
} );

editor.ui.addButton( 'MyWidget', {
    label: 'My Widget',
    command: 'myWidget',
    toolbar: 'basicstyles,1'
} )
```